# "TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable" in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have `is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)` field in user model in my `flask app` now when am loging in, I get the error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

Traceback

```
.
.
.
File "/home/environments/flask0101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/flask/myapp/app/auth/views.py", line 15, in  login
login_user(user)
File "/home/environments/flask0101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 675, in login_user
if not force and not user.is_active():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_active` is bool object.

```
>>> is_active = True
>>> is_active()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Just use it as a predicate, instead of calling it:

```
if not force and not user.is_active:
    ...
```

Comment: But that is a line in `lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py` it's flask file executed when I call `login_user(user)`. How will I login a user instead of `from flask.ext.login import login_user` 
then  `login_user(user)`?

Comment: @Alexxio, How about wrapping a object, with another object which provide `is_active` method?

Comment: Yeah just did that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alexxio, Your solution will not work. It will return the method itself; which is always predicated as truth value.

Comment: @Alexxio, I meant something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9183112/2225682  See `DBUser` there.

Comment: @Alexxio, Try your solution with inactive user. Then you will know what I mean.

Comment: The root cause of this is that you have a field named is_active and flask is asking for you to define it as a function. I am working through this right now, and am looking at renaming is_active to active or something.

Wrapping it in an object that, is hiding a simple issue and changing that line is going against how Flask-Login wants you to work.

Answer (score 6):

Flask-Login 0.3 [contains a breaking change](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/CHANGES#L25-L26) which changed `is_active`, `is_anonymous`, and `is_authenticated` from functions to properties.  If you upgrade now, you would no longer get an error that the `is_active` column is not callable, you could just leave it as a column.  If you wanted to change the behavior, you would decorate the method you write with `@property`.

Answer (score -1):

Given the post date of the original question, I don't believe the 0.3 update is the issue. It did help me though. Thanks davidism!

I found though that with even the latest, v0.3.2, I see this break change throw an error with the Flask Security quick start code. I uninstalled and downgraded to the working 0.2.11 version for now.

```
pip install flask_login==0.2.11
```